# When to create iterator for a list?

Tags: java, collections, arraylist, iterator

Is it possible to do the following?

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
Iterator<String> iterator = list.listIterator();
populateList(list);
```

I am creating a list and getting its iterator before populating the list with data. Will I be able to get the elements of the list using the iterator? Does the order of getting the iterator and populating the array make any difference?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: why don't you try it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it matters. You will get a [ConcurrentModificationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html), when you use `hasNext()` or `next()` on your iterator. `ArrayList`'s iterator is fail-fast, that means it will throw CME as soon as the underlying structuure of the arraylist changes by adding or removing elements.

**Edit:**
Iterator calls `checkForComodification()` first in hasNext() and next()

```
final void checkForComodification() {
        if (modCount != expectedModCount)
        throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Java uses a timestamp on its datastructures. Before you execute the `next()` or `hasNext()` method it will check if the timestamp is equal to the one when you created the iterator.

The reason is that for instance in the case of a `HashSet<T>`, one can define an iterator, but after adding elements, the order is not guaranteed to be the same. Therefore an active iterator could yield some items more than once and others would not be iterated at all.

Comment: In what sense are you using the term `timestamp`?

Comment: I'm not really sure how Java handles this internally (although I think it's quite the same). But `C#` assigns an integer field to each collection. The integer field is set to zero and incremented each time one makes a modification to the collection. When an iterator is created, the iterator copies that integer in a dedicated field. Each time a method of the iterator is called, the iterator will first check if his field is still identical to the timestamp (the integer field) of the collection. If not, the iterator knows he is outdated.

Comment: Then you are correct and deserve my +1.

Answer (score 0):

**Important point about Iterator in Java:**

1) Iterator in Java support generics so always use Generic version of Iterator rather than using Iterator with raw type.

2) If you want to remove objects from Collection than don't use for-each loop instead use Iterator's remove() method to avoid any `ConcurrentModificationException`.

3) Iterating over collection using Iterator is subject to `ConcurrentModificationException` if Collection is modified after Iteration started, but this only happens in case of fail-fast Iterators.

4) There are two types of Iterators in Java, fail-fast and fail-safe.

Example: -

```
List<String> li = new ArrayList<String>();
        li.add("list1");
        li.add("list2");
        li.add("list3");
        System.out.println("Added");

        for(String st:li){
            if(st.equalsIgnoreCase("list1"))
                li.remove("list1");
        }
```

you will get `ConcurrentModificationException` in this case. so modify for loop to make it work.

```
Iterator<String> iter = li.iterator();
        while(iter.hasNext()){
            if(iter.next().equalsIgnoreCase("list1"))
                iter.remove();
        }
```

Read more: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/10/java-iterator-tutorial-example-list.html#ixzz2eSRG7gAT